# How can i log the FTP passwords, that are used to login on a server

Tags: ftp, password

We have to reinstall a webserver where currently images from webcams are uploaded to. We know the username, but not the used password.

Is it possible to log the used FTP passwords (no SFTP/SSL)?

Comment: FTP sends passwords in plaintext so grab wireshark (or other packet capture application ) and run it will connecting. Look at traffic captured for the password

Comment: As above, also check with the FTP provider.

Answer (score 1):

A web server does not have any FTP server passwords, but a FTP server has. If no FTPS (i.e. FTP over SSL) is used you can do a packet capture (wireshark, tcpdump...) on port 21 (ftp) and analyze the packet capture  to extract the usernames and passwords. Look out for the following sequence from the client:

```
 user <username>
 pass <password>
```

This can maybe done with a simple

```
 strings captured.pcap | grep -iE '^(user|pass) '
```